# How to add additional route in laravel4 resource controller

Tags: controller, resources, routes, laravel-4, restful-url

I'm having some problem with laravel4 restful routing. Here is how i got error

**In my route i've following resource for users**

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

According to this i can access all of the method supported by resource . In my **user controller** i want to add new method **getProfile** . it mean i am trying to use method that resource can't support . According to some posts , i am suggested to add

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

finally my routes become

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

By that way i can call `getProfile` from anywhere like this `users/profile`
It went fine .

**But Problem occured when i loaded view in that method**

```
public function getProfile()
    {

        return View::make('users.profile');
    }
```

Can anybody help me out of here

Answer (score 0):

first, i suggest u to read [beware-the-route-to-evil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil) wrote by phil sturgeon. if you want to use resource route with other route you MUST put the other route on the top of the resource route.. for example :

```
Route::get('users/login','UsersController@getLogin');
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

OR

you can just change your controller from

```
public function getLogin()
```

to

```
public function login()
```

hope u find this useful

Answer (score 0):

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

// Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');

Route::get('users/login','UsersController@login');

Route::resource('users', 'UsersController'); 

Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController');
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php

class UsersController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * User Repository
     *
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->user->all();

        return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
    }


    /**
     * 
     * Login Form View
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {       
        return View::make('users.login');
    }



}
```

**User.php(model)**

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' =>  'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|max:32|confirmed'
    );

    /* Relationship */
    public function enquire()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Enquire');
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it got solution but i couldn't satisfied with it . here is how i made it 

`Route::get('users/login', array('as' => 'users.login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login') );`

Comment: what make u not satisfy? and 1 more thing.. don create new answer just edit it

Answer (score 0):

@Sanny Singhts solution is right, but take note that in **routes.php**, you should put the routes in order..

```
Route::get() or Route::post()
```

should always be on top of Route::resource()